# Swap positions UIViews Xcode

Tags: objective-c, xcode, uiview, uiimageview, swap

I am wondering how to swap the positions of two `UIImageViews` in Xcode when they are touching each other.

**Example:**

```
if (CGRectIntersectsRect(view1.frame, view2.frame)) {
   [UIView animateWithDuration:0.2 animations:^{
     CGRect view1Frame = view1.frame;
     view1.frame = view2.frame;
     view2.frame = view1Frame;
   }];
}
```

Unfortunately, this doesn't work because the variable remembers the old position every time.
Can you help me with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following:

```
CGRect view1Frame = view1.frame;
CGRect view2Frame = view2.frame;

if (CGRectIntersectsRect(view1.frame, view2.frame)) {
   [UIView animateWithDuration:0.2 animations:^{
     view1.frame = view2Frame;
     view2.frame = view1Frame;
   }];
}
```

I think this should work I didnt test it but normally this should be fine...
PLease let me know...

In addition: If you want directly change variable inside a block so that they have other value after leaving the block you need to declar them with __block (for details regarding blocks I recommend apple docu http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/conceptual/Blocks/Articles/bxVariables.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007502-CH6-SW6 )

regards

Answer (score 0):

maybe this helps the pointer to the CGRect struct

```
CGRect *view1Frame
```

should be replaced with:

```
CGRect view1Frame = view1.frame;
```

I dont want to go more deep into Structs and Objects because lines between them can blur :D but in that case you just use it CGRect without a pointer. You even get normally a warning from xcode...

thanks regards

Comment: The first time I try my code it works, but the second time it doesn't

Comment: And the * before the variable was a mistake of mine when I typed it.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the current position from your layer's presentation layer.

```
CGPoint currentPos1 = [view1.layer.presentationLayer position];
NSLog(@"%f %f",currentPos1.x,currentPos1.y);
CGPoint currentPos2 = [view2.layer.presentationLayer position];
NSLog(@"%f %f",currentPos2.x,currentPos2.y);
```

After that you can do the animation to swap them...

Comment: I have forgotten to tell you that the UIImageViews are in a NSMutableArray.

Comment: What do you mean by in a NSMutableArray, aren't they(UIImageViews) on the screen???

Comment: No, they are. But they are displayed on the screen with a for loop.

Comment: The weird thing is, the first time when I want to swap two UIImageViews, it works. But the second time when I want to swap them again, it doesn't work. They go back to their original position.

Answer (score 0):

My suspicion is that you are calling this method twice and since they overlap both times the animation is just undoing itself. Try this:

```
BOOL animationDone = NO;

if (CGRectIntersectsRect(view1.frame, view2.frame) && !animationDone) { 
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.2 animations:^{
     CGRect view1Frame = view1.frame;
     view1.frame = view2.frame;
     view2.frame = view1Frame;
     animationDone = YES;
    }];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use tuples to do that :)

```
(view1.frame, view2.frame) = (view2.frame, view1.frame)
```