# Swap positions UIImageViews second time Xcode

Tags: objective-c, xcode, uiimageview, swap

I have a problem. When I use the code below, I can swap the same UIImageViews for the first time. The second time, they go back to their original position or overlay each other.

**Example code:**

```
if (CGRectIntersectsRect(view1.frame, view2.frame)) {
   [UIView animateWithDuration:0.2 animations:^{
     CGRect view1Frame = view1.frame;
     view1.frame = view2.frame;
     view2.frame = view1Frame;
   }];
}
```

How can I swap the positions of the UIImageViews every time?
Help will be much appreciated!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Swap positions UIViews Xcode](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17497337/swap-positions-uiviews-xcode)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you make this into a method?

```
-(void) swapLocWith: (UIView *) view1 and: (UIView *) view2
{
   //your code sample here
}
...
-(void) someMethod
{
    //swap once
    [self swapLocWith: view1 and: view2]; 
    //swap back
    [self swapLocWith: view2 and: view1];
}
```